# Получение json массива из другой веб страница

Tags: php, html, jquery, json, url

Ребят, привет всем. Скажите можно ли через JS получать массив с другого url и передавать на свою страницу.
Допустим есть url https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5 , как получить buy из массива и вывести на свою страницу? Если есть уже подобные решения - скиньте пожалуйста для разбора. Буду благодарен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для запросов можно использовать [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
или [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) ([`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/))

```js
fetch("https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5")
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((arr) =>
    arr.forEach((item) => {
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerText = item.buy;
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    })
  );
```

Comment: Отличное решение, подскажи пожалуйста а как проверять на ID? Вот в другом api есть ещё и ID у валюты, как сделать так, если введённые цифры в инпут совпали с одним из ID в json - тогда выдать информацию по именно введенному ID.

Comment: Максимально очевидный ответ: нужно взять данные из input и сравнить с теми данными которые приходят. `arr` это уже `json` над которым было сделано `JSON.parse`, соответсвнно ищете нужный `id` и при совпадении выводите только его